# KCFinder in https context doesn't browse

Tags: images

First of all, I use CiviCRM 4.6.2 with Drupal 4.7
My website works with a ssl certificate, so the url is https://www...
In CiviCRM I try to send a new email. In The text editor there is a button to insert or edit an image. It open KCFinder but when i click on "browse" to browse and find an image, it doesn't work. In the Google Developer Console it says : "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.xxx.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=tinymce&cms=civicrm&type=image' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I understand this message but I don't know how to fix it...
Any advise ?
Regards,
HashKey

Comment: Any idea please ?

Comment: I changed http to https in my theme css and the message disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I changed http to https in my theme css and the message disappeared.

Now there's still one error.

I changed the editor from tiny or CKE to "default drupal editor". And it WORKS !